# Make fails to parse co-targets (multipe targets) in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Co-targets (i.e. a list of whitespace-separated words for the *target*), is a well-known feature of Make, which basically allows for a makefile to assemble "similar" targets (i.e. they share the same recipe and prerequisites) into a single rule.

***So, I have a makefile, like:***

```make
define targets
foo
bar
baz
endef

$(targets) ::
    @echo '$@'
```

***Executing, I get:***

```console
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
makefile:8: recipe for target 'foo
bar
baz' failed
make: *** [foo
bar
baz] Error 2
```

Really?

Answer (score 1):

```
targets := foo bar baz

$(targets) ::
    @echo '$@'
```

define is used to create a variable that contains newlines. This is not what you want, you just want whitespaces.